# How to chain after-change-hook functions?

Tags: buffers, hooks, markdown, buffer-modified

I am trying to convert markdown to html and then use impatient-mode to display it live on browser on the fly.

Impatient mode uses `after-change-hook` to detect changes in html. I am using `after-change-hook` to detect changes in markdown buffer.

> Buffer changes made while executing the `after-change-functions`
>   don't call any before-change or after-change functions.
>   That's because `inhibit-modification-hooks` is temporarily set non-nil.

As documentation says it won't work.

I can use timer to update every second but I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: Nothing preventing you from `let`-binding this variable to nil before modifying the html buffer.  Just make sure you're not running into an endless loop, which shouldn't happen if the modifications happen in 2 different buffers and the hooks are added locally.

Comment: @politza I thought it will be anti-pattern. Please post it as answer.

Comment: You could also run a timer in the `after-change-function running` after 0 secs, which is like a throw to toplevel.  Those are just ideas.  Try it, and then post  your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As politza mentioned `let` binding of `inhibit-modification-hooks` to nil worked well.

```lisp
(let ((inhibit-modification-hooks nil))
   (my-custom-function))
```